# sql unicode, attributes's characters are broken error in R

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf

my sql question in R programming is below

```
install.packages("data.table")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("sqldf")


library(sqldf)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
customer <- fread("1.txt",sep = ",")

sqldf("select * from customer")
```

when i view the table,
unicode of data in table are okay but attributes of table show broken characters.

Comment: Please add some meat around your question. We don't have access to your data nor we don't see what's suppose to be broken.

Comment: Please use the edit function to add the relevant information.